# What is the meaning of "<+-| alert@+>"?

Tags: beamer

It is used in:

```latex
\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]

\item ...

\end{itemize}
```

It seems that a pause added after every items, but how does `[<+-| alert@+>]` work?

Answer (score 2):

If you open the `beamer` documentation, and search for `[<+-| ale`, the second hit gives you:

[image]